Creating orthomosaic from UAV image
I was provided with UAV data consists of *.JPG and *aux.xml files. I tried to create an orthomosaic using ArcGIS Pro following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_hwOeft0n4&ab_channel=KarenJoyce. However, although images overlap 50-60 percent, images are not stitched together well.


You do not have sufficient overlap in this image set to get a complete orthomosaic.  Refly with more overlap and reprocess your data.  If you search the web you will find that ESRI and DroneDeploy recommend 70%, Agisoft recommends 80% forward and 60% side.
